# Pycharm not recognizing packages even when __init__.py exits

Tags: python, pycharm

This is my directory structure

```
--> ProjectDirectory
          -->__init__.py


          --> BaseDirectory
                  -->__init__.py


          --> AnotherBaseDirectory
                  -->__init__.py

          -->program.py
```

inside `program.py`

When i give `import BaseDirectory`

PyCharm is unable to recognize the package

all `__init__.py` files contain `__all__` variable with the python file names

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 16):

You can try marking root directory as Sources Root. Right click on root directory, and click `Mark Directory As -> Sources Root`

Answer (score 9):

If we set `__init__.py` as a `Text` file type, Pycharm was not indexing it. We need to remove `__init__.py` from the `Text` file type
[image]

Comment: Incredible, this was the issue for me, been trying to debug for a long time. The interpreter was able to read the __init__.py but Pycharm was not indexing it. Intellij please find the reason why this would default to text.

Comment: Thank you! This issue has been annoying me like a gnat for months.

Comment: @Song, to be clear, should the __init__.py be a Text file or something else?  The message you typed was somewhat ambiguous. "Please have a check if ..." and do what as a consequence of checking?  1) please assure that it is a Text file 2) or please check whether it is, and change it to type XYZZY.

Comment: In my case the __init__.py was somehow falsely added to another File Types recognition, therefore Pycharm will not try to read its reference as Python file type. Remove it and the editor will work correctly.

Comment: appreciate man. accidentally added the init file to another file type!!

Comment: Thanks, this was it for me.  In my case, it was under "File type autodetected by file content".  Try typing it explicitly under the python file types and it will give you a warning if it is explicitly declared elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

My problem was that I had a hyphen in the package name `foo-bar`, which also brings other problems with it. Replacing with an underscore: `foo_bar` immediately solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the highlighting is not working for `__init__.py`, that means, that PyCharm thinks it is a different type, so the packages won't work.

The file name patterns can be found in the `Editor > File Types` section in the settings (`File > Settings`)
`__init__.py` can be in categories, like Text, or `File type auto-detected by file content`. You don't need to search, just **put `__init__.py` to the Python category**, and everything will be all right again (after complaining about the init file is already being in other category).

Other problem can be if that **directory** that contains the init file has no **proper name**. If you stick with the [PEP8 file name convention](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) you must be safe, however these names are just a subset of acceptable file names.

[image: Settings > Editor > File Types > Python]

Answer (score 0):

For whoever struggles with this question, I find my solution on Pycharm 2018 as following:

The idea is to run our python code in `-m` way but instead of doing

```
python -m module.a.b arguments
```

we do

```
runpy.py module.a.b arguments
```

As per the [runpy documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/runpy.html), it is the script that

> implements the `-m` command line switch that allows scripts to be
>   located using the Python module namespace rather than the filesystem.

Here are the steps we actually do:

- Find the `runpy.py` located inside the system. For my case, I'm using centos and `runpy.py` is located under `/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py`
- Setup the Pycharm configuration like the following:

[image: Pycharm configuration for running a subpackage script]

In my case, my script that is part of module is (i.e. `module.a.b`) `quickstart.cmd.genXML` and the arguments to the script is `-p .`.

In this way, we can also invoke python debugger inside pycharm against the script as usual.

Reference:

- [SO:running python scripts within a subpackage of my package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048687/running-python-scripts-within-a-subpackage-of-my-package/24052110#24052110)
- [Create a PyCharm configuration that runs a module a la “python -m foo”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081065/create-a-pycharm-configuration-that-runs-a-module-a-la-python-m-foo)

Answer (score 0):

The answers here don't work for me, but the following does (Pycharm community 2018.3):

1. Detach the project from PyCharm
2. Close PyCharm
3. Delete .idea folder from project
4. Launch PyCharm
5. Reopen the project and attach to current window
6. Suddenly the project is recognized as package

Answer (score 0):

what finally fixed this for me as `__init__.py` was not associated as a Text file was going to **Auto-detect file type by content** which is up around the beginning of the **Recognized Files Types** list and removing `__init__.py` from the list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score -1):

You can try by adding the `ProjectDirectory` into the path.
To do that you have to go to:  Settings -> Project Settings -> Project Interpreter and there you can add into the path by pressing +.